# Quantity of specific strings inside a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm working in .net c# and I have a string text = "Whatever text FFF you can FFF imagine";
What i need is to get the quantity of times the "FFF" appears in the string text.
How can i acomplished that?
Thank you.

Comment: I believe "frequency" is the better word than "quantity".

Comment: Does "X FFFF Y" count as zero, one or two matches?

Comment: @polygenelubricants: No, "quantity" is better than "frequency" here. (Though "the number" would be more idiomatic than "the quantity".) A *quantity* merely implies a count. A *frequency* implies a count *with respect to how often it occurs given the size of the sample*. For example, the *quantity* of "FFF" in the given sentence is two. The *frequency* of "FFF" is "every third word".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this and right about anything you want:

```
string s = "Whatever text FFF you can FFF imagine";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(s, Regex.Escape("FFF")).Count);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are 2 approaches. Note that the regex should use the word boundary `\b` metacharacter to avoid incorrectly matching occurrences within other words. The solutions posted so far do not do this, which would incorrectly count "FFF" in "fooFFFbar" as a match.

```
string text = "Whatever text FFF you can FFF imagine fooFFFbar";

// use word boundary to avoid counting occurrences in the middle of a word
string wordToMatch = "FFF";
string pattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(wordToMatch) + @"\b";
int regexCount = Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Count;
Console.WriteLine(regexCount);

// split approach
int count = text.Split(' ').Count(word => word == "FFF");
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: +1 for the useful information. However the OP never specifies that he's counting words so it's a matter of interpretation.

Comment: @João thanks, I +1'd you earlier before deciding to post with these additional approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Matches(text, "FFF").Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex for this:

```
string p = "Whatever text FFF you can FFF imagine";
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("FFF");
var instances = r.Matches(p).Count;
// instances will now equal 2,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to the regular expressions:

```
string s = "Whatever text FFF you can FFF imagine FFF";
//Split be the number of non-FFF entries so we need to subtract one
int count = s.Split(new string[] { "FFF" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Count() - 1;
```

You could easily tweak this to use several different strings if necessary.